# What is another way to say this is because?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a better way to connect these two sentences?

> The smart bandage will also affect the lives of students in the future, when this product is available for regular consumer use. **This is because** many will have the unfortunate wounds or skin conditions of aging parents to tend to and the many likely injuries of children to care for.

Comment: Sure, but first your sentences must be coherent.  The first sentence says that the smart bandage will affect students.  The second sentence talks about the set of people who have serious wounds, tend to aging parents, or care for children.  This set care-givers comprises more than students.  And it seems that the bandage would affect not only the care-givers but also those they care for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also just remove "This is because" and simply start the second sentence with "Many of them."

Answer (score 1):

The author presumes those students will have children when the product is available in the future. And they will also have aged parents to care for. Therefore, those who are students now, will then need the product for both their children and aged parents. It does make sense to me and you could join the sentences using a conjunction. It will become a long sentence, though.

> The smart bandage will also affect the lives of students in the future, when this product is available for regular consumer use, as many of them will have the unfortunate wounds or skin conditions of aging parents to tend to, and the many likely injuries of children to care for.

If you want to keep the two sentences, you could say: "...for regular consumer use. A lot of them will have..."

Answer (score 0):

Another way to say that is: **"due to the fact that"**

> The smart bandage will also affect the lives of students in the
>   future, when this product is available for regular consumer use. This
>   is ***due to the fact that*** many will have the unfortunate wounds or skin
>   conditions of aging parents to tend to and the many likely injuries of
>   children to care for.